# Smart Grid block representation via GUI on a touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

For a science fair of an informative nature I want to present, using a touchscreen, a block representation of smart grid. It should represent users, e. g., houses and buildings, some of which may also produce energy using renewable sources (solar panels, windmills, and such) and traditional energy production plants, with arrows or billboards to represent the energy flows. The users who interact with it must be able to change parameters, like the amount of renewable energy produced, via a GUI widget like, for example, a scroll bar.

I know such systems are simulated in software like Simulink, however I would like to create a kind of GUI that prevents the user from accessing the simulation model but still allows the user to change some parameters, e.g., the amount of renewable energy produced by users, via GUI widgets, e.g., scroll bars. I would like to know:

Does such a simulation system, or something similar, exist?

If not, I would like to develop it in Python. Is there a library aimed at something similar?

Thanks